# add dynamic element into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var x = 0;
    var counter = 0 ;

    $(function () {
        $('#addBtn').click(function () {

                        x++;

                       if (counter < 5) {
                counter++;
                $('#content').append('<input type="text" id="mytxt' + x + '">');
                $('#content').append('<input type="button" id="removeBtn' + x + '" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + x + ')" />');
                $('#content').append('<div id="br' + x + '"/></div>');



            } else {
                alert("you cannot added more than 5 element");
            }


        }
        );



    });




    function removeRow(index) {
        $('#mytxt' + index).remove();
        $('#removeBtn' + index).remove();
        $('#br' + index).remove();
        counter--;
           alert(counter);

    }
```

this is my function to create dynamic button, when i clicked "addBtn", new element will be created and id start with 1,eg: mytxt1, and when i clicked "removeBtn" and "addBtn" again,the id will become mytxt2, the result is out of my expected, 
what i want is when i clicked "removeBtn" and "addBtn" ,the id will start from 1 again,but not 2

new updated

that is one of my question also, if i added more element let said 4 element,the id i get will be mytxt1,mytxt2,mytxt3 and mytxt4, and if i remove mytxt2, the next element i added will become mytxt1,mytxt3,mytxt4,and mytxt5, and this is not what i want,what i want is mytxt1,mytxt2,mytxt3 and mytxt4

Comment: Add `x--;` to your remove function: at the moment on add you're setting your index numbers using the `x` variable, but on remove you're decrementing only the `counter` variable. Note though that it is more complicated that this: what if you add four elements and then remove the second one? What index do you want the next added item to have?

Comment: u state to the point,question edited =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following (untested) code keeps track of which indexes have been used, and allows reuse of indexes formerly associated with removed items. Note that the user could remove items in any order; this code reuses lower indexes first.

```
var maxElements = 5,
    indexes = [];

$(function () {
   $('#addBtn').click(function () {
      // look for a false or undefined index in the array
      // note: index numbers will start at 1 as in the question
      for (var x=1; x <= maxElements; x++) {
         if (!indexes[x]) {
            // found a currently unused index, so use it, and mark as used
            indexes[x] = true;

            $('#content').append('<input type="text" id="mytxt' + x + '">');
            $('#content').append('<input type="button" id="removeBtn' + x 
                        + '" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + x + ')" />');
            $('#content').append('<div id="br' + x + '"/></div>');

            return;
         }
      }

      // no unused index was found
      alert("You cannot added more than " + maxElements + " elements.");
   });
});

function removeRow(index) {
   $('#removeBtn' + index).remove();
   $('#mytxt' + index).remove();
   $('#br' + index).remove();

   // mark index as not used
   indexes[index] = false;
}
```

EDIT: Note, I kept this as similar to your starting code as I could, but I removed the `counter` variable entirely because my code doesn't use it - obviously you can put it back (with corresponding `counter++` and `counter--` in the appropriate places) if you want instant access to the current count of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that none of the Id's match up?

As close as I can tell by your code we have:

```
#myTxt1 == #my1 
#removeBtn1 == #but1 
#br1 == #div1
```

Comment: oops,sorry, that one is just edited problem ,id is not problem at all=)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing function wrapper from your code

```
$(function () {  
// 
 });
```

Comment: May be you have a java script variable scope problems.